# Open File and Continuously Read file with new lines c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to open a file and while it's open, print every line even when the file has been added to?

For Example

Instance 1 > Open File, Read File Data

Instance 2 > Input Data as New Line

Instance 1 > Read New Line Data

Would this be possible in c#?

Comment: Instances 1 and 2 are in the same process? Or different processes?

Comment: can you please be more informative. Are you using console enviroment or Windows forms?

Comment: Console Environment, And 2 Different Programs
Sorry for being unclear

Comment: It depends on how both applications open the file, and how the writing application is doing the writes. If the writing app is Notepad, for instance, then the file is read entirely into memory, edited entirely in memory, and changes are only written when the file is saved, so you can't read from the file as lines are added.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, if you are simply trying to achieve inter process communication (IPC) there are much better (and more efficient) methods.

Comment: If you happen to use this for communicating between two processes, consider using memory-mapped files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `FileShare` enum parameter to the [`FileStream` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) which allows 
you to open the file from multiple sources and use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to monitor changes made to the file.

Comment: This Documentation Explains and Examples it perfectly, Thank you so much!